# Why is React useEffect dependency seemingly ignored?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, dependencies, react-context

I have a React component with two `useEffect` hooks, one of which is meant to only execute when a value stored in context is updated. That hook is executing when the component runs before the context value has changed and I don't understand why.

Following are the code and the console output. My intention with this code is that `apibase` effect hook runs only the first time the function runs (this appears to be working), and that the `getRights` hook only runs after the `apibase` effect hook has run and thus has updated the context-stored value of `apibase` (this is not working).

I can make it work by testing for `apibase !== null` inside the `getRights` hook function, but I'd like to understand why passing `[apibase]` as the dependency array to this effect hook is not working. Any insight would be much appreciated.

```
import React, { useContext, useEffect } from 'react';
import { GlobalContext } from './contexts/globalcontext';
import { xhttpGet } from './utils/xhttp';

const App = (props) => {
    
    const {apibase, setApiBase} = useContext(GlobalContext)
    console.log('App top of function - apibase is: ' + apibase)
   
    //apiBase useEffect - executes only the first time the component runs - WORKING AS EXPECTED
    useEffect(() => {
        console.log('apibase useEffect')
        setApiBase(props.apiroot)
    },[])    
    
    //getRights useEffect - expected to execute only when apibase changes - NOT WORKING AS EXPECTED
    useEffect(() => {
        console.log('getRights useEffect - apibase ' + apibase)
        xhttpGet (apibase + '/user/rights',receiveUserRights,handleNoPermission)
    },[apibase])

    const receiveUserRights = (status,data) => {
        if (status===200) {
            console.log('got the rights')
        }    
    }    

    const handleNoPermission = () => {
        console.log('insufficient permission to call API')
    }    

    if (apibase) {
        console.log('render')
        return (
            <div>This is the app.</div>
        )
    } else {
        console.log('return null')
        return null
    }

}

export default App
```

[image: console output from the above code]

*Note: `xhttpGet` is a function I've written to handle XHTTP requests. The second parameter in that function call is a callback which is invoked after the API response comes back.*

Comment: All `useEffect` hooks will run after the initial render. Is that the issue you're having?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like what you're trying to do is not run an effect on mount. This is commonly done by using a *ref* to track whether the component has mounted. On the first run of the effect, `isMounted` is `false`, but on the second (and all subsequent runs), it's `true`:

```
const isMounted = useRef(false);

useEffect(() => {
  if (!isMounted.current) {
    isMounted.current = true;
    return;
  }

  xhttpGet(apibase + '/user/rights', receiveUserRights, handleNoPermission);
}, [apibase]);
```

I'd like to also note that `receiveUserRights` and `handleNoPermission` should also be in the dependency array of this effect or you'll risk having stale references to those functions. As-is, adding these to the dependency array would cause an infinite loop since they're recreated on each render, so you'll want to memoize them somehow.